# NSLocalizeddescription=cancelled IOS MFP

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

Im getting this errror when trying to hit https server.

> NSLocalizeddescription=cancellel

Which already done pin certificate. But error still happens, anyone can help me?

> NSString *cerPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.cer",[Environment
> cert]]; [[WLClient sharedInstance]
> pinTrustedCertificatePublicKeyFromFile:cerPath];

Comment: What's the return type of `-[Environment cert]`?

Comment: MobileFirstSSLCert_LOCAL_UAT
Coz my cert is MobileFirstSSLCert_LOCAL_UAT.cer

Comment: ... if it's not `NSString` then are you sure `-description` produces something sensible? It's not idiomatic to use `-description` to produce well-defined output, but there's no strict reason why it may not do what you want. But have you double checked that `cerPath` holds something reasonable?

Comment: Should be correct, coz if i anyhow put in string, it will crash the app.
But this wont crash the app

Comment: A common way to implement `-description`, and the way Apple intends, is to return a string that describes the object for the benefit of a human being. It may or may not also be correct syntax for some technical purpose, and may or may not continue to be as code is updated. If I were you I'd add a breakpoint or an `NSLog(@"%@", cerPath);` and see whether what it produces is reasonable.

Comment: Ya i added NSLog. and the result is correct MobileFirstSSLCert_LOCAL_UAT.cer

Comment: When exactly do you see the problem? Is it when the API `pinTrustedCertificate` executes? Or later?